# How to add values to last column of a table based on certain conditions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, display

I have a 29736 x 6 table, which is referred to as table_fault_test_data. It has 6 columns, with names wind_direction, wind_speed, air_temperature, air_pressure, density_hubheight and Fault_Condition respectively. What I want to do is to label the data in the Fault_Condition (last table column with either a 1 or a 0 value, depending on the values in the other columns.

I would like to do the following checks (For eg.)

1. If wind_direction value(column_1) is below 0.0040 and above 359.9940, label 6 th column entry corresponding to the respective row of the table as a 1, else label as 0.
2. Do this for the entire table. Similarly, do this check for others
   like air_temperature, air_pressure and so on. I know that if-else
   will be used for these checks. But, I am really confused as to how I
   can do this for the whole table and add the corresponding value to
   the 6 th column (Maybe using a loop or something).

Any help in this
    regard would be highly appreciated. Many Thanks!

EDIT:
Further clarification: I have a 29736 x 6 table named table_fault_test_data . I want to add values to the 6 th column of table based on conditions as below:-

```
for i = 1:29736 % Iterating over the whole table row by row
    if(1st column value <x  | 1st column value > y)
         % Add 0 to the Corresponding element of 6 th column i.e. table_fault_test_data(i,6)
    elseif (2nd column value <x  | 2nd column value > y)
         % Add 0 to the Corresponding element of 6 th column i.e. table_fault_test_data(i,6)
    elseif ... do this for other cases as well
    else
         % Add 1 to the Corresponding element of 6 th column i.e. table_fault_test_data(i,6)
```

This is the essence of my requirements. I hope this helps in understanding the question better.

Comment: It is not clear with point 1 itself. Could you give proper example with values in the form of small table. It would be greatly helpful for others to help you. Always understanding from text is very much complicated. To avoid conflicts in understanding provide some example

Comment: I have clarified the details. Kindly look into the EDIT. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical indexing, which is supported also for tables (for loops should be avoided, if possible). For example, suppose you want to implement the first condition, and also suppose your x and y are known; also, let us assume your table is called *t*

```
logicalIndecesFirstCondition = t{:,1} < x | t{:,2} >y
```

and then you could refer to the rows which verify this condition using logical indexing (please refer to [logical indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1410)

E.g.:

```
t{logicalIndecesFirstCondition  , 6} = t{logicalIndecesFirstCondition  , 6} + 1.0;
```

This would add 1.0 to the 6th column, for the rows for which the logical condition is true

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I ask why you use t{:,2} > y. Shouldn't it be t{:,1} >y as I want to check if first column value is >y in case of the first condition.

Comment: I am still having issues with the thing. My table, as you say is 29736x6. I am really confused, and I would be thankful if you could write it up in a little more detailed manner. I went through logical indexing and am able to create this thing you have suggested, but I am still not able to understand how do I use this without a for loop. I mean, to be precise, Suppose my 6th column of table is initially all 0, and based on values of other 5 columns (1-5 columns), I would like to put in a 1 there if a particular condition is satisfied.

Comment: as long as your table contains double using curly brackets you refer to the content (not a subtable of your table). So in order to, say, identify the variables on column K that satisfy a certain condition, what you have to do is to expose the content of the table (or, in this case, of the column).

E.g.: suppose you want to add 1.0 to the elements of the 3rd column, but only for the rows for which the second column is positive; you would do it with something like this

rowsWithPosNumbersOnCol2 = t{:,2} > 0 ;
t{rowsWithPosNumbersOnCol2 , 3} = t{rowsWithPosNumbersOnCol2 , 3}  + 1;

Comment: first line: give me logical indexing for which my condition is true (second column is positive);

second line: get the values in the third column for which the condition written on the first line is true and set those equal to their actual value plus one.